# Sparse Checkout in LibGit2Sharp

Tags: git, bash, libgit2sharp

Is there a way to do sparse checkout with Lib2GitSharp?

I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only) (2nd answer) as a reference, executed it manually with git bash and it worked.

The problem is that in this answer the command 'git pull origin master' is executed, and in the Lib2GitSharp I wasn't able to find an exact equivalent (Repository.Pull() does not do the trick..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libgit2 (and thus LibGit2Sharp) doesn't support **sparse checkout** yet.

Indeed, handling of `core.sparsecheckout` and `.git/info/sparse-checkout` is not implement yet. Would you be willing to keep track of its future progress, please open a issue in the **[issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/new)**.

However, LibGit2Sharp exposes a **[CheckoutPaths()](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/IRepository.cs#L110-L119)** method which accepts a list of pathspecs (eg. *"directory-or-file"*, *"directory/"*, *"dir*/*.txt"*, ...). You'll find below an excerpt of the xml doc of this method

> Updates specifed paths in the index and working directory with the versions from the specified branch, reference, or SHA.
>
> This method does not switch branches or update the current repository HEAD.